# Finding position of point (in 3D space ) which are at x,y offset from corner of a rectangle in 3D world

Tags: geometry, 3d

So I am writing a 3D graphic software. And I am stuck at mathematical problem.

Mathematically speaking:

- There's a rectangle  (plane) of finite size in 3D space. It can be of any orientation and at any position in 3D world. Not necessarily parallel to any standard planes formed by axis (ie XY plane or YZ plane or XZ plane)
- I know the four corner point's position in 3D space(ie x,y,z co-ordinates with respect to world center 0,0,0).
- I also know which one among four points is topleft (topleft to camera looking at rectangle), which one is top-right/bottom-left/bottom-right.

Now if we consider rectangle only in 2D (and just forget about 3D world), then take any top-left corner point A, then there can be a point B which is in plane,  and is at offset x, offset y away from corner point.

Here I want the Point B's  position in actual 3D space (x,y,z coordinates) at given offset-x and offset-y values.

Note :

Offset-x  and offset-y  aren't x,y co-ordinates of 3D space. But they are just right and bottom distance (or offset positions) from top-left corner of 2D rectangle itself. (for example if the rectangle is 500 x 500 in dimension, if we take Top-left corner point A and try to find B which is at offset-x = 250 and offset-y = 250 from corner A, then point B will be center point of rectangle.)

What I tried:

- I tried to find line containing top-left corner point A1, and top right corner point A2. And then I could find point 'P' at given offset-x from top-left point on that line.
- Same way I found line containing top-left corner A1 and bottom-left corner A2. And found point 'Q'  at offset-y from top left corner on that line.
- Now B which I needed to find, will be fourth point of rectangle formed by P, Q,  A1.

That's all I know.

Comment: Are the x and y offsets in the 3D space or in the plane of the plane?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you done so far?

Comment: @MartijnPot  x and y are offset in plane (in 2D). 

So , let's say if plane is of 500 x 1000 in dimension .. x and y offset from any corner can be of 500 and 1000 at max respectively.

Comment: @Travis  I have no idea where to start. I can find plane function ax + by + cz = d . But what to do then ? I have no idea. I am poor at Math.

Comment: Do you mean that you're given the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of $B$ and you want to find the $z$-coordinate of $B$?

Comment: You know 4 points of a rectangle in space, and wish to add lengths x1 and y1 to a corner in its plane along lines  parallel to its length and breadth. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Narasimham  Yes . I think you understood it correctly. So far I wrongly used  the word "Plane", I should have used " rectangle" . (As by mathematical definition plane is infinite in length.)

Comment: @Travis I have corrected the question above and have added more information.

Comment: @dsman I think I understand the question know, but perhaps it would be useful for potential answerers if you included your attempt at the problem, with some specific description of what you had trouble with.

Comment: @Travis I haven't been able to do much so far. As I said I am poor in Math.  I obtained equation of plane, the rectangle is in. But couldn't think what to do beyond that. 

And  someone who knows geometric math very well, they can certainly solve this.  

It would help if you remove the "hold" on the question. It is completely relevant to math.stackexchange.com  and I have provided enough information as well.

Comment: @dsman I agree that it is certainly within the scope the site (and an interesting question besides), and it is certainly well-specified now, but in my view it is still missing "context", or more precisely, "...additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it". If you add some description, and in particular what you had difficulty with in setting up the computation, I'll happily nominate the question myself for reopening. (If you do this, please add a comment here so that I'm sure to see it.)

Comment: @Travis I have added explanation of what I tried so far.

Comment: @dsman I see that someone else has already reopened the question since you did, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have found the correct locations of the points $P$ and $Q$ as described in the problem, then indeed $P,$ $A_1,$ and $Q$ are three consecutive vertices of a rectangle and your desired point $B$ is the fourth vertex.

There is no need to be concerned with what kind of motion put your original rectangle at the position and orientation that it has.

Let the three known points have $(x,y,z)$ coordinates as follows:
\begin{align}
P &= (x_P, y_P, z_P), \\
A_1 &= (x_A, y_A, z_A), \\
Q &= (x_Q, y_Q, z_Q),
\end{align}
and name the as-yet-unknown coordinates of $B$ this way:
$$ B = (x_B, y_B, z_B). $$

Because the two sides of a rectangle are parallel and equal in length,
the vector $P - A_1$ is identical to the vector $B - Q.$
Or in other words, the distance and direction from $A_1$ to $P$ is the same as
the distance and direction from $Q$ to $B,$
so you move the exact same way to get from $Q$ to $B$ as you do from $A_1$ to $P.$
For example, in order to go from $A_1$ to $P,$ your $x$ coordinate has to change
by the amount $x_P - x_A,$
so to get from $Q$ to $B$ you have to change the $x$ coordinate by the
same amount; but that change is $x_B - x_Q.$
Therefore $x_P - x_A = x_B - x_Q.$

Solving that last equation for $x_B$ in terms of the three known quantities,
$$ x_B = x_P + x_Q - x_A. $$
The other two coordinates of $B$ can be found in similar ways:
\begin{align}
y_B &= y_P + y_Q - y_A, \\
z_B &= z_P + z_Q - z_A.
\end{align}

---

An alternative method of arriving at the same conclusion is to remember that
the center of a rectangle is also the midpoint of each of its diagonals.
The $x$ coordinate of the midpoint of diagonal $PQ$ is $\frac12(x_P + x_Q)$ and
the $x$ coordinate of the midpoint of diagonal $A_1B$ is $\frac12(x_A + x_B).$
But both midpoints are the exact same point, and its $x$ coordinate has to
be the same no matter which way you compute it:
$$ \frac12(x_P + x_Q) = \frac12(x_A + x_B). $$
Again, solving for $x_B$ in terms of the known quantities in that equation,
$x_B = x_P + x_Q - x_A,$ and the other two coordinates are found by
similar steps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope there's nothing against 'necro'-ing, I'm quite new.

From what I understand of your question you just want the vector describing the distance from an imaginary point in your rectangle ABCD, from a corner A, with all the elements describing only the magnitude of the distance right?

In that case, find out the angle the two rectangles have between them in the x,y plane and the x,z plane, and do a compound rotation through those angles to the vector A you get from the rectangle lying in the x,y plane, then take the magnitudes of that new vector that you get.

The process is like this:

|R[about y]R[about x]A| = A', the vector you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let the corner be $A$, and the nearest vertices of the rectangle be $B$ (right) and $C$ (bottom), and then you have the point $P$ in the plane of the rectangle that you want to determine the offsets from point $A$.

Compute the unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ as follows

$u_1 = \dfrac{B-A}{\| B - A \| } $

$u_2 = \dfrac{C - A}{\|C - A \|} $

Then the offsets are

$ \text{Offset to the right} = u_1 \cdot (P - A) $

$ \text{Offset to the bottom} = u_2 \cdot (P - A) $

That's all.  So using dot product between the vector offset  $(P - A)$ and the unit direction vectors of the two sides, you compute the respective offset along these two sides.